# AngularJS Update list's sub-element efficiently

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently designing a small website using AngularJS. I have a JSON (generated via PHP from MySQL) that I load using a service.
Using ng-repeat I create as many tables as there are elements and, for each table I have an other ng-repeat for each sub-element to create lines.

What I want to do is to add a button that toggles the linked property from false to true and vice-versa. It works but as you can see below, I have to loop all the list to update a particular element.

Here is a sample of my JSON file :

```
{
        "id": 13,
        "active": 1,
        "created": "05/09/2018 18:34",
        "timestamp": "08/10/2018 08:52",
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 789,
            "linked": true,
            "ip_address": "192.168.1.20",
            "comm_string": "public",

          },
          {
            "id": 795,
            "linked": false,
            "ip_address": "192.168.1.80",
            "comm_string": "public",

          },..
          ]
},....
```

Here is the HTML :

```
<table ng-repeat="line in json">
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="child in line.children">
// CONTENT...
  <td>
    <button ng-click="toggleLink(line.id, child.id, child.linked)">
      <i ng-class="{'fa fa-link': !child.linked, 'fa fa-unlink': child.linked}"> 
</i>
{child.linked ? "Unlink" : "Link"}}
</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
<table>
```

Here is the JS :

```
$scope.toggleLink = function (group, device, state) {

// Update entry
        $scope.json.forEach(function (v) {
            if (v.id === group) {
                v.children.forEach(function (u) {
                    if (u.id === device) {
                        u.linked = !state;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
            return false;
        });
```

So this code works but my list will be very big in the future so looking for the right element and then looking for the right subelement might be slow.

Is there a way to update the value of child.linked without using forEach ?
I know that I could to that to toggle the value :

```
<button ng-click="child.linked =! child.linked"></button>
```

But later  I want to do is :

- Click on a button (call the function)
- Make a HTTP POST request to update the database
- Retrieve the new value of child.linked (which of course is supposed to be !child.linked but it's "safer" to get it from DB)
- Then update the subelement in the list to update the view

If you have any idea I would be very grateful, if you need clarification I am at your disposal.

Thanking you in advance,

Comment: I'm confused... why do you need to loop over everything? Just pass `child` into your function and you have an immediate reference to it without looping over everything.

Comment: So something like this : toggleLink(child). Then in JS : child.linked = !state. It works, it's very simple actually. Thank you !